# Trying to develop a formula for relative angle relationships in fixed space

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, coordinate-systems, rotations

Fixed space is defined relative to origin $(0,0,0)$. Fixed space has an origin with angles $(0,0,0)$ as well.

A particle $P$ has $(x,y,z)$ coordinates relative to the origin: $P_x$, $P_y$, and $P_z$.

An observer $O$ has $(x,y,z)$ coordinates relative to the origin: $O_x$, $O_y$, and $O_z$. $O$ also has angles $\theta_{Ox}$, $\theta_{Oy}$, and $\theta_{Oz}$, defined as the rotation about the given axis in fixed space.

The particle and the observer have a restriction in their relationship. $P_z$ is guaranteed to exist on the far half of observers $z$ axis, such that if the observer is facing the particle, the positive $x$ and $y$ axis of the observer are right and up respectively. (The particle is restricted to half the observer's frame of reference.) In other words, the particle has a 0-180 degree domain relative to the observer about the $z$ and $x$ axes.

What I'm trying to find is this: If the observer has given coordinates and rotation relative to the origin and a particle exists with the specified restrictions, what are the three relative ($\theta_{R(x,y,z)}$) angles between the observer and the particle? In other words, a function {$P_x$, $P_y$, $P_z$, $O_x$, $O_y$, $O_z$, $\theta_{Ox}$, $\theta_{Oy}$, $\theta_{Oz}$,} -> {$\theta_{Rx}$, $\theta_{Ry}$, $\theta_{Rz}$} I've come up with several equations that seemed right, only to be quickly disproved. I'm coming to my wit's end on this.

Comment: Just finished adding some clarifying edits, if you just started reading the question. One of my edits was put on the wrong paragraph for about 30 seconds.

Comment: What is the meaning of $\theta_{Ox}$, $\theta_{Oy}$, and $\theta_{Oz}$? Are they some kind of Euler angles of "the" rotation about "the axis"? If so, rotation of what around what point, what is "the axis" that you mentioned, and how could you peform that rotation when (for example) $\theta_{Ox} = \pi/4$, $\theta_{Oy} = \pi/3$, and $\theta_{Oz} = \pi/6$ (measured in radians)? Similar questions apply to  $\theta_{Rx}$, $\theta_{Ry}$, and $\theta_{Rz}$.

Comment: $\theta_{O}$'s are the rotation of the observer. $\theta_{R}$'s are the relative angle between the $O$ frame and the $P$, given that both have position and the observer has rotation relative to some fixed origin. If $\theta_{Ox}$ were $\pi/2$, then $O$'s positive $z$ axis would be parallel with the system's $y$ axis. Imagine that $O$ was a camera sitting on a tripod with a ball joint and that the lens faced in the positive $z$ direction. If $P$ were an apple hanging from a tree, what would it's relative position and angle be to the camera as opposed to the ground.

Comment: It sounds like the $\theta_O$ angles _are_ some kind of Euler angles. There are 24 different ways to define three angles like this. Your description eliminates some of the possibilities, but you need to consider exactly how the three separate rotations are composed in order to get the correct orientation of the camera at the end. It doesn't make sense to give the apple's position in Euler angles, though; are the $\theta_R$ axis-cosine angles? Azimuth and elevation would be just two angles, giving the exact direction to the apple in the camera's frame of reference.

Comment: I am doing some research on the matter and will get back to you as soon as I understand how to answer your question. Sorry for being vague.

Comment: That's OK, a very large part of most worthwhile math problems is figuring out how to formulate them. If you're really stuck, maybe taking a step or two back and describing the actual requirements that led you to this point would help; for example, if you're working with a popular software system that requires input in a particular format, the name of the system would be an important clue (because then we could look up the specs). Your description of the "camera" also is useful in this way, whether it's real or just a metaphor.

Comment: Thanks. I'll add a problem description as an edit as soon as I get the chance. I just didn't want to scare people away with a huge question.